# How to take daily snapshot of table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

One of the tables has to be a hierarchy of product reps and their assigned area. Orese reps and their area change every day, and I need to keep track of what exactly that table looks like every day. I will need to take snapshots of the table daily.  I would like to know what I have to do or how I have to store the data in the table, to be able to know exactly what the data in the table was at a certain point in time.  Is this possible?  Please keep in mind that the table will not be more than one megabyte and table has an incremental load. i do not want to use any tool for it. i want to build logic for it in stored proc only.

Comment: There are multiple questions there, i.e. creating a snapshot table, creating an SP to take a snapshot and scheduling the SP to run daily. Which bits do you need help with?

Comment: Maybe you want ["Temporal Tables"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: creating snapshot table...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DaleBurrell That's harsh ! :)

Comment: @DaleBurrell - https://stackoverflow.com/conduct. Specifically, "No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language"

Comment: There are TONS of documents on this and many different methods so do have a read up! my preference is stored procedure inserting into a table based on one date

Answer (score 4):

You can do one of these:

- Create a new table each day, and copy the data of your table in it;
- Create **one** new table with the same structure as your table, plus one additional date column, to store the date of the snapshot taken, then each day copy your table along with the current system date;
- Make your existing table a [temporal table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017) (as also suggested by sticky bit in the comments). Please note, that you need SQL Server 2016 or newer for this.

My personal preference is the last option, but first two may be easier for you.

For the first 2 options you need to create a [SQL Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017) job to run nightly and take the snapshots. The 3rd option works automatically.

Lets say your table is named `MyTable` and has primary key `ID int` and field `Name varchar(50)`.

For the first option you need to use dynamic SQL, because each time your new table's name will be different:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'select ID, Name into MyTable_' +
    convert(nvarchar(10), getdate(), 112) + N' from MyTable'
exec (@sql)
```

When executed, this statement will create a new table with the same structure as your existing table, but named with the current date as suffix, e.g. `MyTable_20190116`, and copy `MyTable` to it.

For the second option you need to create one table like bellow, and copy data to it using the script like this:

```
create table MyTableDailySnapshots(
    SnapshotDate date not null
    , ID int not null
    , Name varchar(50)
    , constraint PK_MyTableDailySnapshots primary key clustered (SnapshotDate, ID)
)

insert into MyTableDailySnapshots(SnapshotDate, ID, Name)
select GETDATE(), ID, Name
from MyTable
```

If you choose the third option, no actions are needed to maintain the snapshots. Just use query like this, to get the state of the table for a period of time:

```
select ID, Name from MyTable   
for system_time between '2019-01-16 00:00:00.0000000' and '2019-01-16 23:59:59.9999999'
```

The first option is more flexible if you table's schema changes in time, because each day you can create a table with different schema. Options 2 and 3 has only 1 table to store the snapshots, so you may need to be creative, if your table's schema needs to change. But the disadvantage of the first option is the large number of tables created in your database.

So it is up to you to choose what's the best for your case.

Comment: is there any way by which i can take daily snapshot and delete the first day of records on 8th day so i can use this cycle as weekly or seven days also.

Comment: Sure, just delete the older data, e.g. `delete from MyTableDailySnapshots where SnapshotDate < dateadd(day, -7, getdate())`